# Sending email to multiple contacts in outlook using VB script and contact groups

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to send an email notification to a contact group on a calender event.

To do this i am using categories for example the `Send Message` category this will send emails to a specified contact group.

My VB code is below:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Select Case Item.Categories
 Case "Send Message"

 Set objGroup = GetObject _
("LDAP://cn=Scientists,ou=R&D,dc=NA,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")

objGroup.GetInfo

arrMemberOf = objGroup.GetEx("Test")

For Each strMember In arrMemberOf
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strMember)
    strEmail = Replace(objUser.mail, "@", "@internal.")
    emailList = emailList & strEmail & ";"
Next

strTo = emailList

 objMsg.To = strTo
 objMsg.Subject = "BI Test"
    objMsg.Body = "This is a test"
```

I'm not so sure how to set the LDAP parameter, i am new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the code to be VBScript or VBA? They're two different languages despite sharing some similarities.

Comment: I was looking for a vbscript

Comment: The code you posted is VBA, not VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, see below:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Dim Conn
Dim cmd
Dim ToStrn

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server}; server=localhost;user id = sa; password=mypass; Initial Catalog=TestDatabase"
Conn.Open

Select Case Item.Categories
 Case "Send Message"

 Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
 Rs.Open "Select * from Cleints where Rank = 'MNGR'", Conn
 While Not Rs.EOF
    ToStrn = ToStrn + CStr(Rs.Fields.Item("Email")) + "; "
    Rs.MoveNext
 Wend

 objMsg.To = ToStrn
 objMsg.Subject = "SQL Test"
 objMsg.Body = "This is a test message sent via a calender event."
```